# Increase cpu utilization in AIX

Tags: cpu

To perform some test, I have to increase CPU utilization in AIX using python. For ex..
If the total CPU utilization of system prior to running the script is x, then when the program is run, it will be “x + targeted CPU” utilization. I am planning to pass targeted cpu utilization as a argument.

I have written script for Linux which is working correctly but somehow its not working on AIX.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that I would be looking at is to check that the related Linux libraries are installed on your AIX host. Some of the things that AIX does in regards to languages/commands is a little different in the syntax on Linux, so it might be simply your calling the wrong flag within a command. Fortunately there are a number of Linux on AIX tools that you should either be able to get from your rpm source ([IBM AIX Toolbox](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/toolbox/download.html)) or the related CD/DVD that was shipped with you AIX installation image. You can find a list of those packages here: [IBM AIX Toolbox Applications.](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/toolbox/alpha.html)